# how to load *.model file generated by weka into weka Explorer?

Tags: model, classification, weka

I have saved the result of weka classification by right clicking on the model and selecting "save model". Now, I want to load it and work with its classifier. How can I do that?

Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Classify tab, right click in the results list and choose `Load model`, and navigate to your saved model.

Answer (score 1):

You save a trained classifier with the -d option (dumping), e.g.:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t /some/where/train.arff -d /other/place/j48.model
```

And you can load it with -l and use it on a test set, e.g.:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -l /other/place/j48.model -T /some/where/test.arff
```